# how to display an image all PCs on a LAN

Tags: lan

i have 10 pcs connected on a LAN using a 16-port hub...our LAN was setup for educational reasons..my problem is how can i display the image in PC# 1 to all the PCs connected on the network?what program, if any should i use to do that...say i have presentation (ppt) in PC # 1, and as i run the slides, i want also the other PCs to see the slides on their monitor..i know i can use a projector to have a simultaneous viewing, but i jst want to learn how to do it without using a projector...thanks

Comment: You want to display the screen of PC1 to the PCs 2-10? You could set up a VNC server on the primary desktop and then connect the rest of the clients to that session. There's also broadcasting/screen streaming software avalible online athough I couldn't suggest anything.

Answer (score 2):

The typical application to deploy in this scenario is VNC.  There exist free servers for this (mostly for linux) as well as realvnc.

You could also use any number of internet-based meeting services (cisco's webex comes to mind), but these tend to be expensive, and designed toward sharing over the internet (not the LAN).

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called Teamviewer.com which I used for supporting other people (remote access software) but it also have a feature to do an online meeting.

Using Teamviewer on PC1, you can create a meeting, and let all PC2-PC10 to join the meeting. From then on, PC2 - PC10 will be able to see PC1 desktop. And PC1 will have full access of what you want to display to all PCs.

There may be other "Meeting" software which you can use to do similar things, but this one I recommend because I have used it before (and it is free for personal use) and it is fairly easy to set up (and you can even run TeamViewer without having admin rights as it can simply run without installation), and easy to run the meeting.

Hope this helps.